# Using Thor, can I pass the CLI an argument only (not a task) and send it to a default method/task?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

I am using Thor to create a CLI for a Ruby gem that I am making.  The executable would ideally take a command like `myapp path/to/file`, in the sense that I would rather the user not have to define a task, only an argument.

I've looked over the API but [default_task](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor#default_task-class_method) only works when no task/argument is present.

How can I make Thor send this variable file argument to a default method/task, and not interpret it like a task that does not exist?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't accept the answer? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I could not get it working using techniques from the supplied answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thor Executable - Ignore Task Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277604/thor-executable-ignore-task-name)

Answer (score 1):

myapp path/to/file

two part answer:

1) `myapp` ... to use an executable other than 'thor' you will need to utilize the 'thor/runner' library.

2) `path/to/file` can be accomplished in the initialize method, like so:

```
class Something < Thor
  def initialize(*args)
    super
    case @path
      when /something$/; self.class.new([@path],options).do_run
    end
  end

  desc 'do_run', "do something"
  argument :path, :banner=>"path/to/file", :optional=>true
  def do_run
    # something
  end
end
```

Comment: oh, also, easier way to do the 'myapp' thing is to add a shebang line at the top `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` and a `MyApp.start` at the bottom, which is a thor convenience method for just this purpose. Can be a little obscure with arguments, tho